# 1st Java app ever; can't query within database?

Tags: java, mysql

I created my very first app in Java (but was already programming in C# and Python) and have a problem I can't even understand, as debugger messages are extremely user-unfriendly. ;-)

The debugger output looks like this:

> debug: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   Kwestionariusz.MainWindow.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainWindow.java:176)
>     at Kwestionariusz.MainWindow.access$100(MainWindow.java:14)     at
>   Kwestionariusz.MainWindow$2.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:72)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)

It's probably something with this action:

```
if (("".equals(login) ) || ("".equals(password)) || ("".equals(accountType)))
        {}
        else
        {
            Users user;
            user = (Users) db.createNamedQuery("Users.findByLoginAndType")
            .setParameter("login", login)
            .setParameter("company", accountBool)
            .getSingleResult();
            if (password.equals(user.getPassword()))
            {
                JFrame appWindow;
                appWindow = new AppWindow();
                this.setVisible(false);
                appWindow.setVisible(true);       
            }
        }
```

Where:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLoginAndType", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.company = :companyBool LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: Have you gone through this with a debugger to see where the NPE comes?

Comment: What you're seeing is called a *stack trace*. It shows that the exception was thrown by a method called `jButton1ActionPerformed` in the `MainWindow` class at line 176. The method that called that method was at line 14, which was called by `actionPerformed` at 72, and so on. It's a really useful tool, but you'll want to combine it with a debugger - are you using an IDE?

Comment: *"1st Java app ever; can't query within database?"*  Wow! My '1st ever' Java pp. (written every time I install or update a dev. environment) is `HelloWorld`, but 'updating a DB' - you're brave.

Comment: Okay, it was just database connection error, thanks for help and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where it happens:

```
Kwestionariusz.MainWindow.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainWindow.java:176) at
```

Line 176 in MainWindow.java.  Open a text editor, turn on line number display, and go to that line.  Look at all the object references you use on that line - one of them is null.  You need to figure out why you failed to initialize it to point to something useful.

Personally, I think code like this is a huge mistake:

```
if (("".equals(login) ) || ("".equals(password)) || ("".equals(accountType)))
        {}
```

Is there no value at all in reporting which of these three is blank?  What happens if one is null?  What if it has a String with whitespaces only?

I think you're trying to express your contract with the user here, but it's not done using the proper idiom.  Throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` after checking each one would be the way I'd do it.  That's an unchecked exception, so the caller would be forced to deal with it.

Comment: I believe you didn't paste the code you were referring to so I don't know what the huge mistake is... but I guess you are typing about password authentication and I'm aware of the fact it's wrong but it's just "for now" to get all the basics of GUI programming.

Comment: The 176th line is:             
user = (Users) db.createNamedQuery("Users.findByLoginAndType").setParameter("login", login).setParameter("company", accountBool).getSingleResult();
so it's just the place I suspected... still, I don't know why. Am I wrongly setting the parameters or the query is wrong? 

The if (() || () || ()) is just not to do a thing if the user will leave the fields blank... but I guess you're way is much more elegant.

Comment: I did paste from your code, just not the part that has something to do with the NPE.  I'm guessing that db is null.  The best way to tell is to use a good debugger and set a break point.